# After reinstalling windows on my pc I can no longer decrypt a folder I have a valid pfx key for

Tags: windows-10, disk-encryption, efs

The title says it all, I reinstalled windows on my PC by wiping the drive and starting fresh. Before doing that, I copied the certificate key for my encrypted folder. Now on the new windows installation, the certificate installs with its password fine but won’t decrypt my files. What gives?

I have installed the certificate in both certlm (local computer) and certmgr (personal certificates), I have also taken control of the directory from properties.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What tool(s) did you use to encrypt the folder? What tools are you using to decrypt it?